# Python shutil copytree: use ignore function to keep specific files types

Tags: python, copytree

I'm trying to figure out how to copy CAD drawings (".dwg", ".dxf) from a source directory with subfolders to a destination directory and maintaining the original directory and subfolders structure.

- Original Directory: H:\Tanzania...\Bagamoyo_Single_line.dwg
- Source Directory: H:\CAD\Tanzania...\Bagamoyo_Single_line.dwg

I found the following answer from [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) within the following post: [Python Factory Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155382/copying-specific-files-to-a-new-folder-while-maintaining-the-original-subdirect)

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch, filter
from os.path import isdir, join
from shutil import copytree

def include_patterns(*patterns):
    """Factory function that can be used with copytree() ignore parameter.

    Arguments define a sequence of glob-style patterns
    that are used to specify what files to NOT ignore.
    Creates and returns a function that determines this for each directory
    in the file hierarchy rooted at the source directory when used with
    shutil.copytree().
    """
    def _ignore_patterns(path, names):
        keep = set(name for pattern in patterns
                            for name in filter(names, pattern))
        ignore = set(name for name in names
                        if name not in keep and not isdir(join(path, name)))
        return ignore
    return _ignore_patterns

# sample usage

copytree(src_directory, dst_directory,
         ignore=include_patterns('*.dwg', '*.dxf'))
```

Updated: 18:21. The following code works as expected, except that I'd like to ignore folders that don't contain any include_patterns('*.dwg', '*.dxf')

Comment: That code is already demonstrating how to do it. You pass the patterns to `include_patterns`, and the return is a callback that you pass to `copytree`. `copytree` does the work of passing paths and names to the resulting `_ignore_patterns` function as it traverses the tree.

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger I now understand how the following works. I need to amend the following only to copy the tree if there is a match based on my include_patterns so that I don't end up with empty directories.

Answer (score 58):

`shutil` already contains a function `ignore_patterns`, so you don't have to provide your own. Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html):

> ```
> from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns
>
> copytree(source, destination, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.pyc', 'tmp*'))
> ```
>
> This will copy everything except `.pyc` files and files or
> directories whose name starts with `tmp.`

It's a bit tricky (and not strictly necessary) to explain what's going on: `ignore_patterns` returns a function `_ignore_patterns` as its return value, this function gets stuffed into `copytree` as a parameter, and `copytree` calls this function as needed, so you don't have to know or care how to call this function `_ignore_patterns`. It just means that you can exclude certain unneeded cruft files (like `*.pyc`) from being copied. The fact that the name of the function `_ignore_patterns` starts with an underscore is a hint that this function is an implementation detail you may ignore.

`copytree` expects that the folder `destination` doesn't exist yet. It is not a problem that this folder and its subfolders come into existence once `copytree` starts to work, `copytree` knows how to handle that.

Now `include_patterns` is written to do the opposite: ignore everything that's not explicitly included. But it works the same way: you just call it, it returns a function under the hood, and `coptytree` knows what to do with that function:

```
copytree(source, destination, ignore=include_patterns('*.dwg', '*.dxf'))
```

Comment: Hi @Jan , the following function is to generate a dynamic ignore list based on files that I want to keep i.e. CAD ("*.dwg", "*.dxf"), so all other file types are then ignored. I've got the following working, my last hurdle is to exclude folders that have no files within them based on the include_patterns("*.dwg", "*.dxf").

Comment: Where is the include_patterns method defined?

Comment: @AK47 include_patterns is defined in the OP.

Comment: Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: Let's say I have a list (i.e. `mylist=[,*.txt, '*.o']`). How do I pass this list as an argument to `ignore_patterns()`? `ignore_patterns(mylist)` doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: @KcFnMi Did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't remember, check https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5082463+[python]

Comment: @KcFnMi, you need to unpack the values from the list. use: `ignore_patterns(*mylist)`. i tested it and it worked.