# Iterate excel files and output in one folder in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a folder and subfolders structure as follows:

```
D:/src
├─ xyz.xlsx
├─ dist
│  ├─ xyz.xlsx
│  ├─ xxx.zip
│  └─ xxy.xlsx
├─ lib
│  ├─ xy.rar
│  └─ xyx.xlsx
├─ test
│  ├─ xyy.xlsx
│  ├─ x.xls
│  └─ xyz.xlsx
```

I want to extract all excel files (xls or xlsx) from source directory and subdirectories, drop duplicates based on excel file names and put all the unique files in D:/dst directory. How can I the following result in Python? Thanks.
Expected result:

```
D:/dst
├─ xyz.xlsx
├─ xxy.xlsx
├─ xyx.xlsx
├─ xyy.xlsx
├─ x.xls
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls'):
            #print(os.path.join(root, file))
            try:
                df0 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, file))
                #print(df0)
            except:
                continue
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = [columns_selected])
            df1 = df1.append(df0, ignore_index = True)
            print(df1)
            df1.to_excel('test.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: I think you could do all that via `shutil.copytree()`. See question [Copying specific files to a new folder, while maintaining the original subdirectory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155382/copying-specific-files-to-a-new-folder-while-maintaining-the-original-subdirect).

Comment: @ahbon, Any unluck with solving this one yet?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I'll try tomorrow and if I have problem I'll let you know.

Comment: @martineau The solution you've mentioned copy all xlsx and xls files to a new folder D:/dst, but it maintain the original subdirectories. What if I just want put them in a folder and ignore its original subdirectories?

Comment: ahbon: The linked question might not be such a good fit afterall. Your question starts out talking about a "folder and subfolders structure" but you don't show any subfolders (or duplicate excel filenames) in the example source. Also, as far as removing duplicates goes, is the criteria strictly the filename or does file timestamp matter? Please clarify these things.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question. I have three subfolders dist, lib and test in D:/src, and the filename with extention are files.

Comment: There still are no subfolders (or duplicate excel files) shown under `D:/src`.

Comment: Yes, dist, lib and test are subfolders under D:/src. and xyz.xlsx under D:/src and D:/src/dist are duplicates by name. BTW, I update what I have tried code. Please check., thanks.

Comment: Is my update to your question correct? Also, if there are duplicate excel file names, which one do you want?

Comment: Yes. Much better, thanks for your correction.

Comment: My filenames are quite long and specific, so if the files share same name, keep any one would be OK. But if you need some rules to drop duplicates, let's say keep the one from lowest level and drop the one from upper level.

Comment: The excel files are like the examples in this post, I want to concatenate all excel files into one, please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347081/locate-dataframe-and-concatenate-based-on-specific-headers-in-python

Comment: While all that pandas dataframe stuff you added is kind of distracting and not exactly relevant to your question, it has however exposed—I think—what is called an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because it reveals _why_ you want to do this file copying. If I am understand things correctly, then there really is no need to copy all the files to a single folder first—just use the process that finds them to copy to instead drive the concatenation of them you want to do. This will greatly reduce the I/O that needs to be done.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your help and remarks. Anyway, I think it will be helpful to manually deal with those excel files in only one folder rather than multiple subfolders. BTW, I'm new in Python, would you please take a look post below if it's possible to concatenate all excel files in one based on specific header columns and ignore the rest？  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347081/locate-dataframe-and-concatenate-based-on-specific-headers-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
import os
import shutil


src = os.path.abspath(r'.\_src')
dst = os.path.abspath(r'.\_dst')
wanted = {'.xls', '.xlsx'}

copied = set()

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
    for filename in filenames:
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if ext in wanted and filename not in copied:
            src_filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            shutil.copy(src_filepath, dst)
            copied.add(filename)
```

Comment: Your solution perfectly solved my copying excel files to one folder issues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ahbon: That's good to hear and you're welcome. Sorry about any distraction my `shutil.copytree()` suggestion may have caused. While it _could_ be done with it, in this situation it would not have been a very good approach.

Comment: Was about to share [this answer you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161407/1431750) for another question.

Comment: @aneroid: I, too, originally thought that answer would be a good approach, but when I was finally—after much discussion—able to understand what the goal was, decided it wouldn't. Although technically it would be possible by "abusing" the `ignore` option to point where it ignored everything is a little too much in my opinion. All that's need for this question is the ability to walk the file folder system hierarchy, so [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) would be the more logical (and better) choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already got `glob.glob`, you don't need to also do `os.walk`, and vice-versa. But since glob only matches one pattern at a time and no way to denote an optional extra 'x' in the extension, you'll either need the `glob` loop twice - once for each extension; or use `glob.glob( 'D:\\src\\*.xls*')` which could match `'*.xlsm'`, etc.

For each file matched, use [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
for file in glob.glob('D:\\src\\*.xls*'):
    shutil.move(file, 'D:\\dst\\' + os.path.basename(file))
```

With `os.walk`, you can do each extension check with [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) in the same loop:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\\src'):
    for file in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.xls') or fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.xlsx'):
            shutil.move(f'{root}\\{file}', f'D:\\dst\\{file}')
            # shutil.move(root + '\\' + file, 'D:\\dst\\' + file)
```

Comment: Why bother calling `os.walk()` only to then quit after first iteration? I think the question is unclear and have asked the OP for clarification.

Comment: Thanks @aneroid. I think shutil.copy would be better for without changing original data, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution only copy D:/src - xyz.xlsx to D:/dst, not excel files from its subfolders.

Comment: @martineau I gathered from the OP's code that he/she wanted to stop after the first folder/iteration. Even with glob, we'd need two loops for each extension, and without `recursive=True`. So figured `os.walk()` could simplify that. Anyway, from OP's post, they did want to do subdirs.

Comment: @ahbon Yes, you can use `copy` instead of `move` if you want the original data to remain in `'D:\src'`. I've removed the `break` so that loop doesn't stop after the first iteration. From your code, it looked like you only want to use the top-level. Also, if you are recursively copying, then `f'D:\\dst\\{file}'` will need to be modified to have the parent folders of each file. Otherwise it will copy flat, without the subdirs. Look at [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) for that.

Comment: aneroid: I guess we disagree in our understanding of what the OP wants. It sounds to me like every subdirectory is going to need to be visited in order to find all the files that will need to be copied.

Comment: martineau: Indeed, we'd need to recurse [sic]. But I got the impression the OP had a flat folder structure at 'src'. That was incorrect since it's now clear that the OP had & wanted subdirs too.